# How to probe the recursiveness order of a sequence $\{S_n\}$ whose generating function is known

Tags: differential-equations, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

How to probe the recursiveness order of a sequence $\{S_n\}$ whose   generating function is known:

$$ \sum_{n\geq0} S_n z^n= \frac{4 z \left(\sqrt{49 z^2-18 z+1}+7 z-1\right)}{\sqrt{49
   z^2-18 z+1} \left(\sqrt{49 z^2-18 z+1}+15 z-1\right)
   \left(3 \sqrt{49 z^2-18 z+1}+21 z-1\right)}+\frac{3}{3-44
   z} $$

And even more, as the following is proven.

$  \textbf{Conjecture}$ :  $\{S_n\}$  satisfy the following recurrence

$$ 0= P_0(n)  S_n+  P_1(n)  S_{n-1}+ P_2(n)  S_{n-2}+ P_3(n)  S_{n-3}+ P_4(n)  S_{n-4}$$

where $P_i(n) \in \mathbb{R}[n]$ are polynomials  of degree 2.

Comment: It is a differential equation for the function (of order 4, with corresponding polynomial coefficients). You may check whether it is satisfied by direct differentiating.

Comment: ... and in this case, unless I'm mistaken, the recurrence is
$$\left(12 n^{2}-1581 n +1569\right) S_{n}+\left(-572 n^{2}+75469 n -111467\right) S_{n -1}+\left(9636 n^{2}-1273335 n +2500019\right) S_{n -2}+\left(-64964 n^{2}+8600211 n -21072477\right) S_{n -3}+\left(129360 n^{2}-17172540 n +50353380\right) S_{n -4}
 = 0
$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173685/how-to-probe-the-order-4-recursiveness-of-the-sequence-s-n-whose-generatin

Comment: @Fedor Petrov  Why do you know a priori that the order of the differential equation is 4.

Comment: Sorry, of order 2, I misread the question. That's because the degrees of polynomials do not exceed 2

Comment: @Fedor Petrov So you say that the generating function satisfies a second-order differential equation.
$$p_0(z) + p_1(z) y(z)+ p_2(z) y''(z)=0$$
And do you know what are the degrees of the polynomials $p_0, p_1,p_2$?.

Answer (score 2):

Extended comment.

The relation $$0=P_0(n)  S_n+  P_1(n)  S_{n-1}+ P_2(n)  S_{n-2}+ P_3(n)  S_{n-3}+ P_4(n)  S_{n-4}$$
for all $n\geqslant 4$ is equivalent to
$$
0=\sum_{n\geqslant 4} (P_0(n)  S_n+  P_1(n)  S_{n-1}+ P_2(n)  S_{n-2}+ P_3(n)  S_{n-3}+ P_4(n)  S_{n-4})x^n.
$$
Denote $\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n x^n=f(x)$. Then $f'(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0} S_n\cdot nx^{n-1}$, $f''(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0} S_n\cdot n(n-1)x^{n-2}$. Thus for $i\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ we have $$\sum_{n\geqslant 4} P_i(n)S_{n-i}x^n=
\sum_{n\geqslant i} P_i(n)S_{n-i}x^n-\sum_{n=i}^3P_i(n)S_{n-i}x^i=\\
\sum_{n\geqslant 0} P_i(n+i)S_{n}x^{n+i}-\sum_{n=i}^3P_i(n)S_{n-i}x^i.$$
Denote $P_i(n+i)=a_i+b_in+c_in(n-1)$ and $\sum_{n=i}^3P_i(n)S_{n-i}x^i=g_i(x)$. Then $$\sum_{n\geqslant 0} P_i(n+i)S_{n}x^{n+i}-\sum_{n=i}^3P_i(n)S_{n-i}x^i=x^i(a_if(x)+b_ixf'(x)+c_ix^2f''(x))-g_i(x).$$
Thus the differential equation for $f$ has a form
$$
q_0(x)f(x)+xq_1(x)f'(x)+x^2q_2(x)f''(x)=A(x)
$$
for some polynomials $q_0,q_1,q_2$ of degree at most 4 and $A$ of degree at most 3.

Comment: @Alexey Ustinov So with what they have said it is easy to probe the conjecture  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173685/how-to-probe-the-order-4-recursiveness-of-the-sequence-s-n-whose-generatin ?

I still don't see it clear.